# php sql drop rate system

Tags: php, sql

This question might seem a bit bizarre, but...

I run a mafia style game site scripted in PHP. When players do crimes, theres a chance they'll get a 'drop', lets say a new weapon.

How I have it working at the moment is each crime they do, I run a rand() out of 10, and if it hits 10 then I randomly select a row from the firearms_db table, and give them that.

What I'd like to do though, is make it so each weapon has a different percentage rate of 'dropping'- so the more powerful and expensive ones will drop less, and the cheap ones will drop frequently. At the moment you've got just as much chance of getting a cheap one as you are an expensive one.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could go about adding this? Would I need to add another field to the firearms_db with a drop rate value and then work with that?

Comment: I believe you're looking to implement [Probability with Percentage](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Probability-Statistics-2077/2008/5/probability-percentage.htm) (i.e. specify the chances of each item).

Comment: can you show your db schema.  The short answer is yes adding another column that would allow for rating the weapons would probably be the easiest.  How else would tell the rating of the weapon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try adding a column to the table that ranks the weapons some way. For example, you could have a `rocket_launcher` rated at 10, while a `toothpick` is rated as 2.

The database table could look like this:

```
+---------------------------------+
|    weapon           |  rating   |
|    rocket_launcher  |  10       |
|    toothpick        |  2        |
+---------------------------------+
```

You could do a `rand()` out of ten. Let's say you store the result in res. Then, query the database:

```
SELECT * FROM weapons WHERE rating <= res
```

If res is 7, then you will only get `toothpick`. If res is 10, you will get both `toothpick` and `rocket_launcher`.

You could then randomly pick the weapon to give, out of the ones from the query.

Comment: wouldn't this method still give you the same probability of getting a top weapon or a crap one?

Comment: It would give you the same probability if the first `rand()` outputs 10. If your first `rand()` is lower than ten, then you would not be able to get that weapon - it would be harder to get a `rocket_launcher` than a `toothpick`. Once you culled the top weapons out, you would have the same chance of getting any weapon from the results of the query.

Comment: Ok thanks, so my query would be something like `SELECT * FROM db_firearms WHERE rating <= '$res' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to always pick an item, and then use the drop rate column to decide whether or not they actually get it. you can make it a % chance, and just store it as an int.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a formula: for a given level of weapon and kind of weapon, you get the "drop" rate. You can use logarithmic/exponential to get a non-linear curve.

you can also use a very simple formula :

> chanceOfDrop = (maxprice-priceOfWeapon)/maxprice * randomFactor()

with randomFactor() between -0.8 and 1.2 for instance.

Comment: what so I'd store the drop rate as a new field in that weapons table entry? How would I pull a record based on drop rate probabilities then? Sorry if I misunderstood, not very good with maths :P